# How to Plot Specific ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, plot-themes

I would like to plot the following list

```
heatmap={{0., 0.0533333, 0., 0., 0., 0.0272, 0., 0.0448, 0.0197333, 
  0.0181333}, {0.1568, 0., 0.128267, 0.1112, 0., 0.0408, 0.0381333, 
  0.0757333, 0.0397333, 0.145067}, {0., 0.16, 0.0768, 0., 0.0824, 
  0.244267, 0., 0.0584, 0.0693333, 0.0181333}, {0.1568, 0.16, 0.0128, 
  0., 0.0824, 0.108533, 0.0381333, 0.0205333, 0.0397333, 
  0.0181333}, {0., 0., 0.0256, 0., 0., 0.2104, 0.0762667, 0.0138667, 
  0.0496, 0.}, {0.1568, 0.0533333, 0.0128, 0., 0.0824, 0.108533, 0., 
  0.123733, 0.0792, 0.0725333}, {0.1568, 0.106667, 0.0128, 0.222133, 
  0., 0.0474667, 0., 0.0104, 0.00986667, 0.0362667}, {0.3136, 
  0.0533333, 0.0384, 0., 0.0274667, 0.0338667, 0.381067, 0.1272, 
  0.00986667, 0.1088}, {0., 0., 0.0128, 0., 0., 0.0136, 0., 0.0205333,
   0., 0.0362667}, {0., 0., 0., 0.1112, 0.192533, 0., 0., 0.0205333, 
  0.0298667, 0.0181333}, {0.3136, 0.213333, 0.230667, 0.1112, 
  0.137333, 0.264533, 0., 0.264533, 0.198133, 0.526133}, {0., 0., 
  0.0128, 0., 0.109867, 0.0338667, 0., 0.0688, 0.0893333, 0.}, {0., 
  0.106667, 0.0384, 0., 0., 0.0338667, 0., 0.0928, 0.0298667, 
  0.0725333}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0202667, 0.1144, 0.0309333, 
  0.00986667, 0.}, {0.470667, 0.426667, 0.128267, 0., 0.549867, 
  0.4208, 0.0381333, 0.319467, 0.475733, 0.0544}, {0., 0., 0.0768, 1.,
   0., 0.0338667, 0.152267, 0.00693333, 0., 0.253867}, {0., 0.0533333,
   0.0256, 0., 0., 0.0610667, 0., 0.0378667, 0.0792, 0.0906667}, {0., 
  0., 0.0384, 0., 0.0274667, 0.0408, 0., 0.0138667, 0.0197333, 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.22, 0.0202667, 0., 0.0653333, 0.0397333, 
  0.0181333}, {0.470667, 0.16, 0.333333, 0.1112, 0.109867, 0.162933, 
  0.1144, 0.1752, 0.188267, 0.0906667}, {0., 0.0533333, 0.256533, 0., 
  0.137333, 0.0677333, 0.0381333, 0.123733, 0.0693333, 0.3992}, {0., 
  0., 0.0256, 0., 0., 0.0136, 0., 0.0514667, 0.00986667, 
  0.0181333}, {0., 0.106667, 0., 0.1112, 0., 0.0136, 0., 0.0274667, 
  0.0496, 0.}, {0., 0.0533333, 0.115467, 0.1112, 0.165067, 0.115467, 
  0.457067, 0.0653333, 0.109067, 0.0906667}, {0., 0., 0.0512, 0., 
  0.0549333, 0.0408, 0., 0.158133, 0.0496, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.0512, 0., 
  0.0274667, 0.0882667, 0.228533, 0.00693333, 0.168533, 0.}, {0., 
  0.16, 0.0256, 0., 0., 0.0202667, 0., 0.0789333, 0.00986667, 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0.0768, 0., 0., 0., 0.0762667, 0.0413333, 0.00986667, 
  0.1088}, {0., 0.0533333, 0.0512, 0., 0.192533, 0.0746667, 0., 
  0.0893333, 0.0992, 0.0906667}, {0., 0., 0.0512, 0., 0.0274667, 0., 
  0., 0.048, 0.0397333, 0.0181333}, {0., 0., 0.064, 0., 0.0274667, 0.,
   0.0381333, 0.00346667, 0.0298667, 0.0906667}, {0.1568, 0., 
  0.410133, 0., 0., 0.0474667, 0., 0.147733, 0.0496, 0.0725333}, {0., 
  0.16, 0.0512, 0., 0.137333, 0.0813333, 0., 0.0962667, 0.317333, 
  0.0181333}, {0.1568, 0.48, 0.205067, 0.777867, 0.247467, 0.0408, 
  0.876267, 0.0549333, 0.0496, 0.181333}, {0., 0.0533333, 0.0256, 0., 
  0.0274667, 0.0408, 0., 0.0344, 0.0298667, 0.}, {0.1568, 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0.0949333, 0., 0.048, 0.0992, 0.}};
```

using ListContourPlot. The expected and my plots are shown in figure below:

[image]

I would like to represent each point in the graph as a square not as a rectangle. Furthermore, I would like represent the colors and legend bar as by figure shown above. Finally, I would like to replace the numbers on the x-axis by months {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} -> {January, February, March, April, May, June, July,August, September, October}.

```
ListContourPlot[heatmap, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All]]
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? At a glance, I would start looking into `AspectRatio` and `ColorFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `ArrayPlot`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"]

xTicks = Thread[{Range[10], {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
     "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct"}}]
xRTicks = {First@#, Rotate[Last@#, π/2]} & /@ xTicks


col[x_] := 
 Blend[{White, RGBColor[0.5761666, 0.8195192, 0.9884546], RGBColor[
   0.2541886, 0.4613372, 0.8892074], RGBColor[
   0.2635842, 0.22089488000000002`, 0.7407538]}, x]


ArrayPlot[heatmap
 , AspectRatio -> 2
 , ColorFunction -> col
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {xRTicks, None}}
 , PlotLegends -> Automatic
 , FrameLabel -> {{None, "Heatmap Topics-Words"}, {None, None}}
 ]
```

[image]

Either `xTicks` or `xRTicks` can be used. The color scheme can be improved.